# How to make and call a function if it has a loop inside of it?

Tags: php, arrays, function, for-loop

I have a for loop that displays all of the images inside of an array. How can I put that inside of a function, so when I need it I can call it and it will show all of the pictures?

```
$countArray = count($fil[0]);

function displayAllImages(){
for ($x=0; $x<$countArray; $x++){
    echo '<img src="photos/'.$fil[0][$x].'" /><br />';
}
}
displayAllImages(); //nothing shows up
```

Comment: This is basic PHP use `$counTArray`, `$fil` as a parameter

Comment: Use `$fil` as a parameter and use a `foreach` in the function. No need for `$countArray`.

Comment: Or use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) and filter specific image file extensions. Otherwise, if you have anything other than image files, they will show those too.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it has a loop inside or not, you call a function the way you call a function.  But you need to learn to indent properly so you can tell at a glance whether the brackets are for the loop or the function.

Comment: Also just use [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) please.

Answer (score 2):

Since you declared $fil and $countArray outside the function, you have no access to them, so you should pass the array as a function argument

```
function displayAllImages($images){
  $counter = count($images[0]);
  for ($x=0; $x < $counter; $x++){
      echo '<img src="photos/'.$images[0][$x].'" /><br />';
  }
}
displayAllImages($countArray, $fil); //now it will show up
```

The best way to do such a thing would probably be the following using the foreach loop:

```
function displayAllImages($imagesSources){
  foreach($imagesSources as $value){
    echo '<img src="photos/'.$value.'" /><br />';
  }
}

$images = array("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png");
displayAllImages($images);

$images = array("0" => array("image1.png", "image2.png", "image3.png"));
//in this case you can pass directly $images[0] to the function as pointed in the comments
displayAllImages($images[0]);
```

and as pointed in the comments have a look at php variable scope [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: This is completely wrong! You don't use `$counter` in the function and `$array` is an array and not a value

Comment: Could you indent this please? And you'll probably need `count($array)` in the `for` loop (as Mario points out, a `foreach` is better anyway).

Comment: You only need to pass `$fil` into the function. The `count()` can be easily calculated from `$fil` - but you don't need the count anyway - just use `foreach()` instead to traverse the array.

Comment: sry its late here and my brain went crazy for a while! I added indent and fixed the variable names, plus i added the better way to do it with the foreach, this assuming that your array is containing the images in the $fil[0] so that $fill[0][0] has an src, $fill[0][1] has another src and so on..

Comment: ... or pass `$fil[0]` instead in that case.

Comment: Really to be an answer rather than just a "here go, here's some code" you need to explain variable scope at least a little.  Really, this question should have been closed or marked as duplicate of a variable scope question probably.

Comment: And you should never call a variable simply `$array` - give it a meaningful name, like you called your outer array `$images`... `foreach ($images as $filename)` - anything to make it easier to read, lessens bugs further down the road when the code gets bigger, etc.

Answer (score 1):

the reason is, that you use a variabe inside a function, that is not declared
activate error_reporting, and PHP should note, that $countArray isn't declared.

2 possibilities:

giving the functino the Array as a Parameter:

```
// $fil[0] is an array

function displayAllImages($a)
{
    if(is_array($a)) foreach($a as $i => $v)
    {
        echo '<img src="photos/'.$v.'" /><br />';
    }
}
displayAllImages($fil[0]);
```

or you tell PHP inside the function, that you want to use a variable outside the function:

```
// $fil[0] is an array

function displayAllImages()
{
    global $fil;
    if(is_array($fil[0])) foreach($fil[0] as $i => $v)
    {
        echo '<img src="photos/'.$v.'" /><br />';
    }
}
displayAllImages();
```

please look at http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Just to emphasise that referencing a global var inside the function is not the preferred way. (`global $fill` - should only be one `l`)

Comment: even for this purpose it would be better to pass a reference i think, but at first he sould think of variable scopes ;)

Comment: No need to pass-by-reference here. The array is not being changed. (PHP implements copy-on-write.)